# After updating to latest Firebase I am getting error "Unable to merge dex"

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on application, after updating to latest firebase I am get error "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex"

build.gradle(Project)

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
}
}
allprojects {
     repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

 }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

build.gradle(Module)

```
      apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
     compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.vishalverma.androideatitserver"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dexOptions {

    jumboMode true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

     }
}

dependencies {
implementation ('com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:v1.1')
implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

//Support library
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27+'
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27+'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27+'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27+'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27+'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27+'
//Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.2'

//Location
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'

//Retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.2.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Did you try cleaning and rebuilding project?

Comment: yes Sir, Serveral times

Comment: implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5' is a problem...